# IsNull() function not recognized in pentaho modified java script

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, pdi, null-check

I am trying to assign a value to and output field based on an input field inside the modified **Javascript** step. I have coded as:

```
 if ( !(person_id.isNull()) )
person_nm = substr(another_field,1,10)
else
person_nm = "";
```

When I run this I get the error:-

> Modified Java Script Value.0 - Javascript error: 
>   Modified Java Script Value.0 - TypeError: Cannot find function isNull in object 7853. (script#90)

1. So where am I going wrong?
2. In the else part I am actually supposed to assign a *NULL* to `person_nm` but I can't find a way to do so. Whats the way this can be achieved?

Thanks,
Kanishk

Answer (score 1):

`IsNull()` is not a vanilla *Javascript* function. It’s available in a number of frameworks, e.g. *jQuery*, but not in *plain JS*.

In *plain JS*, you can do:

```
if(!person_id)
    person_nm = substr(another_field,1,10)
else
    person_nm = "";
```

Comment: Yours worked. I tried `if (var === null)` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

In modified java script you can use below condition.

```
  If (abc === null)
  {
  }
```